# For a smooth function $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert F(x) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert$, is $F'(x)$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question is as above.

Given a smooth function $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert F(x) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert$ but NOT necessarily linear,

could we give any kind of bound on the derivative $F'(x)$, possibly depending on $x$? This derivative is of course $n \times n$ matrix, but we can use any matrix norm since we are in finite dimensions.

Comment: The estimate has nothing to do with the rate of change of the function for $x\neq 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $F'(x)$ can be unbounded, as the function $F(x) = \sin(x^2)$ shows. If you want a counterexample $F: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ then you can take $F_j(x) = \sin(x_j^2)$ in each component.

There is also no uniform bound of $F'(x)$ for all such functions even if a dependency on $x$ is allowed, as $F(x) = \sin(x^k)$ with integers $k \ge 2$ shows.